# Haversine formula error in c#

Tags: c#, geolocation

I'm programming in c#. I want to calculate new latitude longitude using old latitude longitude using bearing and range. I use this formula:

φ2 = asin( sin φ1 ⋅ cos δ + cos φ1 ⋅ sin δ ⋅ cos θ ) 
λ2 = λ1 + atan2( sin θ ⋅ sin δ ⋅ cos φ1, cos δ − sin φ1 ⋅ sin φ2 )

where   φ is latitude, λ is longitude, θ is the bearing (clockwise from north), δ is the angular distance d/R; d being the distance travelled, R the earth’s radius

from [this site](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html).

and here is my c# code:

```
/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
/// <param name="oldLat">old latitude (radian)</param>
/// <param name="oldLon">old langitude (radian)</param>
/// <param name="range">range</param>
/// <param name="bearing">(radian)</param>
/// <param name="earthRadius"></param>
/// <param name="newLat">new latitude (radian)</param>
/// <param name="newLon">new longitude (radian)</param>
public static void CalculateNewLatLon(
        double oldLat, double oldLon,
        double range, double bearing, double earthRadius,
        out double newLat, out double newLon)
{
    newLat = Math.Asin(Math.Sin(oldLat) * Math.Cos(range / earthRadius) + Math.Cos(oldLat) * Math.Sin(range / earthRadius) * Math.Cos(bearing));
    newLon = oldLon + Math.Atan2(Math.Sin(bearing) * Math.Sin(range / earthRadius) * Math.Cos(oldLat), Math.Cos(range / earthRadius) - Math.Sin(oldLat) * Math.Sin(newLat));
}


/// <summary>
/// Calculate new latitude and longitude according to old latitude and longitude
/// Note: All values which are related to geography are in degree unites
/// </summary>
/// <param name="oldLatitudeDegree">old latitude degree</param>
/// <param name="oldLatitudeMinute">old latitude minute</param>
/// <param name="oldLatitudeSecond">old latitude second</param>
/// <param name="oldLongtitudeDegree">old longitude degree</param>
/// <param name="oldLongtitudeMinute">old longitude minute</param>
/// <param name="oldLongtitudeSecond">old longitude second</param>
/// <param name="range">range</param>
/// <param name="bearing">bearing of movement (degree)</param>
/// <param name="earthRadius">radius of earth</param>
/// <param name="newLatitudeDegree">new latitude degree</param>
/// <param name="newLatitudeMinute">new latitude minute</param>
/// <param name="newLatitudeSecond">new latitude second</param>
/// <param name="newLongtitudeDegree">new longitude degree</param>
/// <param name="newLongtitudeMinute">new longitude minute</param>
/// <param name="newLongtitudeSecond">new longitude second</param>
public static void CalculateNewLatLon(
        double oldLatitudeDegree, double oldLatitudeMinute, double oldLatitudeSecond,
        double oldLongtitudeDegree, double oldLongtitudeMinute, double oldLongtitudeSecond,
        double range, double bearing, double earthRadius,
        out double newLatitudeDegree, out double newLatitudeMinute, out double newLatitudeSecond,
        out double newLongtitudeDegree, out double newLongtitudeMinute, out double newLongtitudeSecond)
{
    // Convert geographian DEG, MIN, SEC latitude to decimal degree
    double decimalOldLatitudeDegree = Util.Converter.DegMinSecToDeg(
            oldLatitudeDegree, oldLatitudeMinute, oldLatitudeSecond);

    // Convert geographian DEG, MIN, SEC longtitude to decimal degree
    double decimalOldLongtitudeDegree = Util.Converter.DegMinSecToDeg(
            oldLongtitudeDegree, oldLongtitudeMinute, oldLongtitudeSecond);

    // Convert degree latitude to radian
    double oldLatitudeRadian = Util.Converter.DegreeToRadian(decimalOldLatitudeDegree);

    // Convert degree longtitude to radian
    double oldLongtitudeRadian = Util.Converter.DegreeToRadian(decimalOldLongtitudeDegree);

    bearing = Util.Converter.DegreeToRadian(bearing);

    // Calculating new latitude and new longtitude
    // according to old latitude, old longtitude,
    // range, bearing and earth radius
    double newLatitudeRadian, newLongtitudeRadian;
    CalculateNewLatLon(
            oldLatitudeRadian, oldLongtitudeRadian,
            range, bearing, earthRadius,
            out newLatitudeRadian, out newLongtitudeRadian);

    // Convert radian latitude longtitude to degree
    double decimalNewLatitudeDegree = Util.Converter.RadianToDegree(newLatitudeRadian);
    double decimalNewLongtitudeDegree = Util.Converter.RadianToDegree(newLongtitudeRadian);

    // Convert decimal latitude degree to geographian DEG, MIN, SEC
    Util.Converter.DegToDegMinSec(decimalNewLatitudeDegree,
            out newLatitudeDegree, out newLatitudeMinute, out newLatitudeSecond);

    // Convert decimal latitude degree to geographian DEG, MIN, SEC
    Util.Converter.DegToDegMinSec(decimalNewLongtitudeDegree,
            out newLongtitudeDegree, out newLongtitudeMinute, out newLongtitudeSecond);
}
```

At range = 96NM (nautical mile = 1825 meters) I see a great difference between values in real world and the values which are calculated though according to named web site my code works excellent.

What is the problem?
have Haversine formula a great error?
Or my code is written in a wrong way?

**Note**: that all other converting methods are tested.

Comment: did you check for some simple cases (move 1 deg north, etc) and followed the calculations with a) pencil and paper b) the debugger?

Comment: Yes of course. I checked it as you said. all values are matched with site values but they have great (several minutes) difference in comparison to real values of places.